# Summing parts of an array in python(A rolling window to sum spicific parts of an array)

Tags: python, numpy, cross-correlation

Deal all,

I have data in the form of a numpy array and want to perform summation on parts of the array:

Example:

```
X=[[1, 2, 3,4],
  [5, 6, 7,8]]
```

I want the output to be the summation of elements that within 2x2 window.

Output Needed:

```
[[14],[22]]
```

This is similar to cross-correlation with ones(2,2) but i want the shift to be more than ones element.

This is just an example and the actual data is very large so i cannot manually calculate them. I need a for loop to do that but struggling to do it.

Your Help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to try a nested `for` loop. You should post what you have tried in your question so that we can suggest modifications you need to make/help you understand what's not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way:

```
window_size = 2 # 2x2
res = np.array(np.array_split(X.sum(axis=0),window_size)).sum(axis=1)
```

output:

```
>> [14 22]
```

Comment: let me know how fast it is

Comment: Hi my data is actually a 20x307200 array. i want to reshape each element (each row) into (640,480) then run a summing window to sum all elements in a (20x20) window. the result should be an array of lists where each list is the sum of elements in each window. the length of each list should be 307200/400= 768

Comment: @AminAmer first you asked a question and now you are changing your question, second, I can't follow what you are explaining

Answer (score 0):

You can `reshape` to 2 columns in "Fortran" order and `sum`:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
              [5, 6, 7, 8]])
X.reshape(-1, 2, order='F').sum(0)
```

output: `array([14, 22])`

With more columns you should probably generalize with:

```
X.reshape(-1, X.shape[1]//2, order='F').sum(0)
```

Comment: Hi my data is actually a 20x307200 array. i want to reshape each element (each row) into (640,480) then run a summing window to sum all elements in a (20x20) window. the result should be an array of lists where each list is the sum of elements in each window. the length of each list should be 307200/400= 768